# How to replace a supply plenum box with a blower sitting on top of it

Tags: hvac, ducts

I'll probably hire a professional, but I was curious if it's easy to replace a supply plenum box that already has a blower sitting on top of it.  How would that be replaced, do you have to keep it lifted/suspended somehow keeping all the fittings while you replace the box below, or do you have to completely disconnect the hvac above and then reassemble all the fittings and connections?

I have to replace because of sewer flooding got to the box touching the ground and there is internal insulation in the ductwork that got soaked.

The former seems easier if possible, but not sure if that's prudent or possible.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does that box go below the floor?

Comment: I am confused, do you have 2 separate blower units? Regardless, the basement is considered a conditioned space so the insulation can probably just be ripped out. When you say "sewer flooding" are you implying sewage or just rain water? If it wasn't waste water then you can try running the blower 24/7 for a few days to see if it will dry out the insulation. If there is any sign of mold or funky smells after a few days then rip out the insulation.

Comment: To answer your exact question: Yes, you either have to suspend the blower or disconnect it and move it out of the way. Regardless of which method is used you have to be super careful with those rigid gas connections. You'll have to leak test all of them after replacing the lower plenum.

Comment: The box does not go below the floor.  They are 2 separate blowers, and it was wastewater that came up 6" so the insulation has to be removed if we are keeping the boxes in place.

Comment: blower you say? another six inches and there's a proverb about how bad that would be.