# How to seal the frayed fiberglass border of internal duct insulation in the middle of a duct

Tags: hvac, insulation, ducts

I had to remove the bottom foot of internal duct insulation touching the ground due to sewage backup.

Now that there is a frayed edge of internal insulation inside the ductwork with the remaining insulation continuing above the flood water line. Is there something I can use to prevent loose fiberglass fibers from this border from going into my return airflow?

I saw that there are some insulation edge sealing sprays, but in this case it's not at the end of a duct but in the middle.  Can I tape down the edges with a mastic foil tape, or does that not work because it wouldn't stick to the insulation?

What's the easiest way to seal the frayed fiberglass insulation border in the inside of my return duct?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Will stick to the insulation, but only to the fibres on the surface, very weak holding power.  Can you place the tape on  solid surfaces to cover open fibres?

Comment: it would only be half I suppose... i.e. 1/2 on the bare metal and 1/2 on the fiber ends

Comment: Your return air filter should be stopping the insulation from making it into your airflow. If a large chunk breaks off then you obviously need to remove it so that it doesn't impede air flow.

Comment: Is this a follow-up to https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/234493/42053? If so, please provide a picture of the frayed insulation. I assume this is just some foil-faced stuff?

Comment: Just one end of the tape on metal will just pull off the fibre in time, need both ends on metal/solid surface to last.

Comment: I just had my furnace/AC replaced. I stood in the garage and watched the guy cut the insulation board. He had a knife (looked purpose built, not a std utility knife) and it made _extremely_ clean cuts in the insulation board. My thought, therefore is that you _shouldn't_ have frayed edges. I'd submit that you need to recut 1-2" higher, maybe with a thin, very sharp knife (and use a straight edge - if you're cutting in place, you may need to clamp a backer board _inside_ the existing duct) and you won't have frayed edges to deal with, either.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes it is a follow-up to that post - I had someone come in and they just scraped and pulled off the insulation without a cutter.  It was not a clean cut as shown in the pictures.  The difficulty is that it's hard to reach to the top 2 feet of the remaining insulation because it goes around the side and straight up so would need to cut an access panel to get to the rest.  At which point I think it would probably be easier just to rip it all out.   Wondering if there is an easy way I can just reach in with a sprayer into the hole rather than cutting a panel out.

Comment: @FreeMan unfortunately it's in a hard to reach spot where I wouldn't be able to get to it to make a clean cut without cutting an access hole

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend cold weather foil tape. That stuff sticks to everything. You could also use epoxy resin tape (Tuck Tape) uses on Tyvek on exterior walls. Both stick to just about everything.